# will infinite php loop crash MySQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, infinite-loop

*If I have this `PHP` code :*

```
<?php
  set_time_limit(0); 
  //mysql connection

  while(true)
  {
    //check for updates in mysql (mysql_query...mysql_num_rows...)
    flush(); 
    ob_flush(); 
    sleep(3);
  }

?>
```

*My Questions :*

**Won't this code overload my MySQL server?**

**If I will have 1000 users online won't this code cause problems?**

Comment: omg. why do you need this code? maybe this has to be called from js via ajax?

Comment: It won't overload your MySQL server any more than people visiting your website and querying your database every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yeah, it will. It scales badly.

It would be better to **put a fast layer in between**, like a memcached or a redis. Something that runs in RAM.

There is no need to let *every* user check if the database did an update. Let one check it, and share the results with the others using the fastlayer.

Check the fast-layer when the last database-query was done. If it was more than 3 seconds ago, do a new db-query and update the fast layer. Else, just take the value from the fast layer.

Comment: Or better yet, have the client/service/whatever that performs the `UPDATE` notify waiting clients that an update has occurred.